# Save as PDF a "Numbers" sheet using applescript

Tags: pdf, applescript, save-as

I state that I am not a programmer and I have no experience with applescript.
I try to save as PDF a "Numbers" sheet using an applescripts service because i want
to start the saving process when i need.

```
enter code here

activate application "Numbers"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Numbers"
        keystroke "p" using command down
        delay 0.2
        keystroke "p" using command down
        delay 0.2
                    
    end tell
end tell
```

After the keystroke "p" command i have to select  in a pop up the pulls down button "pdf" and select the option "Save as PDF".
How i proceed?

[pdf button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnssO.png)

Then i will need  in the next pop up to put the value of my variable "nameFile" as the name of the file i want to save.
And also for this step i don't know how to proceed...

Answer (score 0):

No need GUI scripting for this task. Here is simple script, which exports Numbers document to the desktop, as PDF. You can edit the destination folder and the name of resulting pdf (variable docName)

```
set desktopFolder to (path to desktop) as text

tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    set docName to name of document 1
    set PDFExportFileName to desktopFolder & docName & ".pdf"
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    try
        make new file at desktop with properties {name:(docName & ".pdf")}
    end try
end tell

tell application "Numbers" to export document 1 to file PDFExportFileName as PDF
```

Comment: Testing only in **macOS Catalina**, I find the `tell application "Finder"` _block_ unnecessary and the export occurs successfully without using it. Note however, as coded, if the target _file_ already exists it will be overwritten without warning.